# How to prevent compaction in CouchDB?

Tags: nosql, couchdb

What if I need to save all revisions forever, how to prevent compaction in CouchDB?
May i disable this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you fully understand the implications, it's not a good idea to save revisions forever by disabling compaction. If you have a requirement to store historical versions of documents, you can absolutely build this on CouchDB, but you should do it explicitly.

There is a blog post [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100813192647/http://blog.couch.io/post/632718824/simple-document-versioning-with-couchdb) which describes a number of different approaches. If you don't need to index historical documents, I'd recommend storing each revision as an attachment on save. From that blog post,

> when the document is loaded from the CouchDB server, the string
>   representation is saved before being parsed into JSON. Later, when the
>   document is saved, the string representation is attached as a new
>   binary attachment, with the corresponding rev as it’s name, and a
>   content type of application/json. This way any CouchDB library can
>   just open the stored rev, and see it as a normal document.
>
> This means that each time the document is updated, the client will
>   also store the previous version as an attachment to the latest
>   version. At any time, a user can load any of the old versions.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't "disable" the feature... but you don't have to ever run it either.

Comment: It runs automatically.  Then the compaction crashes because there is not enough free space on the disk.  CouchDB needs more than TWO TIMES THE USED SPACE FREE when compaction runs.  Hence disabling compaction would allow to reorganize the databases.  However as compaction autostarts, it always crashes faster than there is a way to recover the data.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/1753#issuecomment-441057368 for a possible way.

Have not tested it out myself but seems to indicate that it is possible.