# CouchDB 3.2 disable auto compaction for a specific database

Tags: couchdb, data-compaction

How can I disable auto compaction in couchdb 3.2?
I want to preserve all the history for a specific database.
Or completely disable auto compaction.

note) couchdb(3.2) configuration has changed from 2.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent compaction in CouchDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20820041/how-to-prevent-compaction-in-couchdb)

Comment: No. It says about couchdb 2.0. configuration has changed in 3.2. I would rather not do auto compaction at all if I cannot configure for a specific database file.

Comment: I did not find anything in the docs. What happens when you set [doc_buffer_size](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.0/config/compaction.html#database_compaction/doc_buffer_size) to 0?

Comment: Yes, documentation is little bit vague about auto compaction. Auto compaction happens once in a blue moon that It is difficult to test by setting some parameters.

Comment: I just found that: [autocompaction](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/248569/disabling-auto-compaction-in-couchdb) which says there is no option to set it to false ... but version info is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from github issue page.(https://github.com/apache/couchdb-documentation/issues/734)
Below is the contents.

---

We do not advise pausing compaction to preserve the history of database. Once database revisions reach past 1000 (_revs_limit) they will start to be removed anyway. Database history should be preserved by the application. When documents are updated, can create a separate document with the old contents and link them together with an ID.

Compaction can be disabled if there is an operational issue of some sort, There is a [smoosh.ignore] $dbshard = true configuration value which can be set for individual shards. For instance:

```
[smoosh.ignore]
shards/80000000-ffffffff/db1.1122445 = true
```

But you'll have to list all the db shards there.

If you want to disable all dbs compaction can try:

```
[smoosh]
db_channels = upgrade_dbs
```